# Crear un CSV con cabecera y fecha en el nombre del archivo

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Buenos días y gracias de antemano,
Por un lado soy capaz de generar un csv con la cabecera "incrustada" en la primera fila. Y por otro también he conseguido (siguiendo respuestas de esta web) crear un csv con la fecha como titulo de archivo. El problema lo tengo al intentar "unir" las dos soluciones, no soy capaz de hacerlo funcionar. A veces da error de sintaxis otra no da error, pero no lo ejecuta...
Adjunto los codigos que "manejo" por si me podeis ayudar:

-- GENERAR CSV CON CABECERA --

```
SELECT 'ID','Fecha','Hora','PRESION','COUNTER2','COUNTER3','COUNTER4'
UNION all
SELECT ID,Fecha,Hora,FORMAT(PRESION, 2, 'es_ES')PRESION,COUNTER2,COUNTER3,COUNTER4
FROM mytbl6
INTO OUTFILE 'D:/Descargas/Prueba8.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

-- GENERAR CSV CON FECHA EN EL TITULO --

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `Prueba`
ON SCHEDULE  AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Respaldo de Ordenes cada fin de mes' 
DO
BEGIN
    SET @sql_stmt := concat("SELECT * FROM mytbl6 INTO OUTFILE 'D:/Descargas/", DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d'), "_orders.csv'");
        PREPARE extrct FROM @sql_stmt;
        EXECUTE extrct;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE extrct;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacerlo así:

1. Creas una variable, por ejemplo, `@sql_stmt` donde guardas como texto la consulta que genera el CSV con encabezados
   Usando `CONCAT` ingresas la fecha donde indicas el nombre del archivo.
2. Creas una sentencia preparada usando el texto en la variable.
3. Ejecutas la consulta.

#### Ejemplo:

```
# Paso 1
SET @sql_stmt := CONCAT("SELECT 
    'ID','Fecha','Hora','PRESION','COUNTER2','COUNTER3','COUNTER4'
  UNION all
    SELECT ID,Fecha,Hora,FORMAT(PRESION, 2, 'es_ES')PRESION,COUNTER2,COUNTER3,COUNTER4
    FROM mytbl6
  INTO OUTFILE 'D:/Descargas/orders_", DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d'), ".csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';");
# Paso 2
PREPARE extrct FROM @sql_stmt;
# Paso 3
EXECUTE extrct;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE extrct;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! es lo que necesitaba. Gracias

Comment: Hola @Mikel, si la respuesta te sirvio, considera votarla y/o marcala como aceptada. Para más info podes resivar [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos!